# No Data in Mongo

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

Using Mongoose in NodeJS I'm able to create a database and insert data and find the data when using mongoose, however when I use the mongo shell with show dbs command it shows the database but the size of the database constantly remains at 0. Is there something I'm missing? Here's my code

```
mongoose = require('mongoose');
Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/dt');

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  first_name: String,
  last_name: String
});

var users = mongoose.model('Users',UserSchema);

var new_user = new users({ first_name: "firstname",
                           last_name: "lastname" });

new_user.save(function(err) {
  if(err) return;
  else console.log("saved");
});

users.find({first_name:'firstname'}).exec(function(err,data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: I had the same problem once. If I remember correctly the data was there even though size showed 0. Try using `db.collection.find()` and see if it returns anything.

Comment: Yeah that seems to be working thanks!

Comment: No problem, happy to help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you might need to use the `insert()` method

e.g

```
db.detail.insert(
   {
      "data" : {
         "name" : "any_name",
         "zipcode" : "10075",
      },
   }
)
```

After which you can use the `find()` method returns query results in a cursor, which is an iterable object that yields documents.

You can read more from [Insert a Document](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/shell/insert/) and [Find or Query Data with the mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/shell/query/)